# EJS include script at start/end of page layout

Tags: javascript, templates, ejs

I am using EJS as a templating engine and am wondering how I would go about including a script that is only required on one page at the end of the page layout.

Example:

layout:

```
<head>
   //Scripts and stuff
</head>
<body>
   <article>
     <%-body%> // Render page here
   </article>
</body>
```

page:

```
    //This script needs to go within the head of the layout
    //Or before the closing </body> tag in the layout, but only
    //when this particular page is loaded.
    <script src="onlyRequiredOnThisPageWithinTheLayout.js"></script> 
    <p>Page content</p>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

include your module page inside article tag.`<%- include("page.ejs") %>`

inside head tag of the layout  write a script to append `<script></script>` tag to the `head` tag

layout.ejs

```
    <head>
    <script>
    function clean(){
        sc=document.querySelectorAll(".pagescript");
        head=document.getElementsByTagName("head");

        for(s=0;s<sc.length;s++){

          head[0].appendChild(sc[s]);
         }
        }
    document.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", clean, false );

   </script>    
   </head>
    <body>
       <article>
         <%- include("page.ejs") %> // Render page here
       </article>
    </body>
```

your page.ejs

```
<script class="pagescript" src="onlyRequiredOnThisPageWithinTheLayout.js"></script> 
    <p>Page content</p>
```

I have taken loop to append script tags, use `sc[0]` if you have only one script tag.